# В чём ошибка запроса?

Tags: phpmyadmin, sql, mysql

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `goods` 
WHERE
`tags` LIKE  '%t1%'
AND
`tags` LIKE  '%t2%'
```

Comment: Да так и есть=)) Спасибо

Comment: @Флекс, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Какая именно у вас ошибка? Выдает неверные результаты или выдает какую-то ошибку (и какую?)?

И `AND` значит - `и то, и другое`. Вам же, скорее всего, надо `или то, или другое`, а значит надо `OR`.